# Why time format is changing in Azure Databricks

Tags: sql, azure, datetime, databricks, sql-timestamp

I have a file with a timestamp with time format as `2017-01-20 16:53:05.212` (`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`).

I have uploaded this file to Azure data lake gen 2 and accessed that file into Azure Databricks.
But when I have executed the below simple query in Databricks notebook.
Time format was getting changed to `2017-01-20T16:53:05.212+0000` (`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ`).

query:

```
Select * from dsd_file_temp
```

I don't want to change my time format.

Comment: Dates in SQL and Python are binary values, they have no format. What you think is a different value format is actually a different *display* format. Besides, both formats are essentially the same, ISO8601. The full ISO8601 uses `T` as a separator between date and time but most applications omit it when displaying dates to users

Answer (score 0):

The default timestamp format in Azure databricks includes the time-zone.

[image]

You can use [date_format()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/date_format) to get the required value.

```
select date_format(to_timestamp('2017-01-20 16:53:05.212'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') as dt2;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering NiharikaMoola-MT. By doing above mentioned method. The format of column is changing to String type(timestamp to string). Can you say how can keep format as timestamp only.